# Data is not changing using onDataChange after using reusable component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I created a reusable component Text input and I want to do a simple validation but i cant get the input value as it always showing null.

This is where I am getting my username and password

```
                <LoginTextBox placeholderName='Email'
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
                ></LoginTextBox>
                <LoginTextBox placeholderName='Password'
                 value={this.state.password}
                 onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                ></LoginTextBox>
                <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={this.onLogin}>
```

This is where I created LoginTextBox

```
    render() {
  return (
       <TextInput
        placeholder={this.props.placeholderName}
        style={styles.input}>{this.props.value}</TextInput>
  );
}
```

Following is my validation

```
  onLogin=()=> {
const { username, password } = this.state;
if (username.match("bhaskarj61@gmail.com")) {
this.props.navigation.navigate('NewsFeed');
}
else {
  Alert.alert('enter valid email')
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChangeText` -attribute never gets attached to your `TextInput` -component.

You could do something similar like this.

LoginTextBox -component render-method

```
render(){ 
  return(
     <TextInput
      {...this.props}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholderName}
      style={styles.input}>{this.props.value}</TextInput>
   )
}
```

and here `{...this.props}` on TextInput component passes your `onChangeText` listener to actual React Native -component.

In this case this would pass `value`, `placeholderName` and `onChangeText` attributes to actual component. You could this way also shorthand `placeholderName` to just use `placeholder`.